# prove $(\mathbb{U} \oplus \mathbb{W})^{\perp} \subseteq \mathbb{U}^{\perp}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{V}$ be a n-dimensional vector space with an inner product. And $\mathbb{U}, \mathbb{W}$ be subspace of $\mathbb{V}$, and $\mathbb{U} \cap \mathbb{W}=\{ \vec{0} \}$

How do I prove $(\mathbb{U} \oplus \mathbb{W})^{\perp} \subseteq \mathbb{U}^{\perp}$? My reasoning is $\mathbb{U} \oplus \mathbb{W} = \{ \vec{u} + \vec{w}, \vec{u} \in \mathbb{U}, \vec{w} \in \mathbb{W} \}$.

Then since $\mathbb{U} \oplus \mathbb{W}$ is a finite n-dimensional vector space, then $(\mathbb{U} \oplus \mathbb{W})^{\perp} \in \mathbb{V}$. I can also trivially say that $\mathbb{U}^{\perp} \in \mathbb{V}$. So how do I finally arrive at $(\mathbb{U} \oplus \mathbb{W})^{\perp} \subseteq \mathbb{U}^{\perp}$?

Comment: You should say $U^{\perp} \subset V$ not $U \in V$.

Comment: Examine what happens to some vector $x$ is it is orthogonal to $u$ but not $u + w$. I recommend sketching an example in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Use the bilinearity of the inner product to formalize your observations into a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, if $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then

$$W^{\perp} = \{ v \in V : \langle v, w \rangle = 0 \textrm{ for all } w \in W \}.$$

Something even more general is true than what you want: if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$, with $W_1 \subseteq W_2$, then $W_2^{\perp} \subseteq W_1^{\perp}$.  That is, the orthogonal complement reverses the containment of subspaces.

The proof is an easy definition chase.